# When I pass in an array to a method and reorder it it reorders it outside the method as well

Tags: c#, arrays

C# keeps changing  all of my arrays when I call the `Array.Sort(targetArray)` inside of a pass by value method.

I have tried making a copy of the array and it just reordered that one too.

```
string[] someArray = (6, 5, 7, 8)

int someVal = ValFromMethod(someArray);
Console.Write(someArray);
//Prints 5678 on the console
//Want it to print 6578

static int ValFromMethod(string[] array)
    {
        Array.Sort(array);
        int temp = array.Length - 3;
        string finalStr = array[temp / 2];
        int final;
        int.TryParse(fainalStr, out final);
        return final;
    }
```

Comment: Arrays are passed by reference.

Comment: Arrays are reference types so the value being passed is a reference to the array. You need to create a new array e.g. `ValFromMethod(someArray.ToArray())`.

Comment: Can they be passed by value in anyway shape or form?

Comment: No. They are reference types. They will not be passed by value.

Comment: Thanks that is good to know

Comment: The terminology used in these comments are slightly misleading. You're passing a reference, by value. What it means is that you cannot make the caller (outside) use a completely different array instance after the call by manipulating that variable inside the method. However, the object it refers to can be changed. Passing *by* value and passing *a* value are two different things, same is passing *by* reference and passing *a* reference.

Comment: So you're right in that you're passing the array reference by value. The method gets its own reference. That reference, however, is referring to the same array instance as the reference used outside of the method, there is only one array.

Comment: How would I create two arrays one sorted and one not?

Comment: `var sorted = array.OrderBy(z => z).ToArray();`

Comment: Thanks so much guys (and girls) this really helped!